# how do I set the proxy for a metro app?

Tags: c#, proxy, microsoft-metro

I'm new to c# and visual studio..

Currently I'm developing a windows 8 metro application.
I want to know how to set system proxy using that application.

A tried to use webProxy class from System.Net. But it says webProxy does not exist in references although I have referenced System.Net..

Comment: You can't.  Store apps can't mess with system settings.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT apps can't set this setting, but you can set the SO proxy.